# Can the preposition "toward" follow the verb "ask"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, translation

I searched for the phrase "ask toward" but found nothing. The thing is it is a translated term, and I want to know if it is *used* or at least accepted in English.

> And ask stars and winds, also **ask toward** clouds.

I'm telling the reader to ask the clouds while looking to their direction. So the person would do both actions at once. It isn't the same with *stars* and *winds*, for example, since the person would direct the question to them but not necessarily look at them.

---

*It's a sentence in a poem.*

Comment: In poetry many times it's up to the reader's point of view if he sees something fit. In that specific sentence, some may understand it as looking toward them, and some may understand it as "referring" the question to them but not looking directly at them. If you want to make things clear for the reader, and you want the reader to specifically LOOK at them, then I believe this will not do. "And ask stars and winds, also ask the clouds while looking at them," you can also make it, "also ask, looking at the clouds," which is less to my liking but still works. Just an opinion, GL :)

Comment: Thank you! It would work fine with both meanings - the important thing is that it **is** actually a natural phrase in English.

Comment: In normal English, it would be unnatural to say *ask stars and winds*. (Semantics aside, it would be *ask **the** stars and* ***the wind***.) But this is poetry. So however you assess the first part of the sentence, you would assess the second part in the same way.

Comment: @JasonBassford _ Is it **necessary** to make both sides identical in the structure if it is poetry? Because I care more about it being **correct** and natural, so if it is not necessary, I would go with your correction.

Comment: @TasneemZH No, it's not necessary. Whatever rules there are in regular English, there are even less in poetry.

Comment: @JasonBassford _ Great! Thank you. I would omit the second "the" (the definite article before "wind") because of the coordinator "and", it would be okay I think.